# Set all Attributes of Document to the values of nested query

Tags: database, nosql, arangodb, aql

In my ArangoDB I'm trying to implement some kind of inheritance.
I have a parent-document which defines all of its children. So, the values are all the same, except for an Inheritance-ID.

So given the case the parent-document has values like:

```
ID: 1
InhID: 0
Name: Doc_1
```

And its children look like this:

```
ID: 1
InhID: 1
Name: Doc_1 


ID: 1
InhID: 2
Name: Doc_1
```

As I'm changing the name from `Doc_1` to anything else in the parent all of its children would also be changed, same goes for a newly added attributes.

The current way is manually writing an AQL-Update query for each attribute updating all of the values one by one setting it to the values of parent where the ID is the same and the InhID is greater than zero.

But is there a more efficient way to do this in one statement? And is there something like a trigger-function like in conventional databases?

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have the data in a test1 collection with fields: ParentID, InhID, Name, Potatoe

Assuming I understand what you are trying to do, you could:

Update the parent and the children all at once with something like:

```
for t in test1
Filter t.ParentID == 1 
update t WITH { Potatoe: "baked" , Name: "Doc_2"} IN test1
```

Update the parent first and then the children (at some other time I assume):

Step1

```
for t in test1
Filter t.ParentID == 1 AND t.InhID == 0
update t WITH { Potatoe: "baked" , Name: "Doc_2"} IN test1
```

Step 2

```
let Parent = (for p in test1
    Filter p.ParentID == 1 AND p.InhID == 0
    return p)
for p1 in Parent 
    for Children in test1
    Filter Children.ParentID == p1.ParentID AND Children.InhID > p1.InhID
    update Children WITH {Potatoe: p1.Potatoe, Name: p1.Name} IN test1
```

In terms of triggers, there is no such thing in Arango. I personally think that is good because triggers tend to cause more trouble than they are worth. I would instead build a middle layer with the required logic and have all external programs go through the middle layer instead of hitting the collections directly. You could build this in the Arango Foxx layer which sits in the DB itself. [Here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/Manual/Foxx/) is documentation to Foxx

Finally, have you thought about changing the structure of the db from a single table that contains both the data and an implicit inheritance relationship (based on the InhID) to a collection and an explicit inheritance relationship using an edge relationship? Depending on what you are doing, it may (or may not) be useful.